# Como verificar se uma data da tabela é inferior ao dia de hoje em Doctrine - Postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine, symfony

Eu tenho que verificar se o usuário cadastrou uma data de validade, se sim, verifico se essa data é inferior ao dia de hoje se for, ele mostra se não ele esconde, fiz assim:

```
        $this->noticia = Doctrine::getTable('Noticias')->createQuery('s')
            ->select('s.*')
                    ->where("situacao = ?", 'ativo')
                    ->where("data_validade < ", 'date("Y-m-d")') 
              // tentei dessa maneira tambem
              // criei uma variavel la em cima no escopo ++ $data = date("Y-m-d");
             // e chamei ela assim(embaixo) 
             // ->where("data_validade < ") . $data
            ->orderBy('data_cadastro desc')
            //->limit(5) // temp
            ->execute();
```

mas no navegador, a página fica toda em branco e nao aparece nenhum erro. hum. O que pode ser ?

Comment: Você esta chamado dois `where` ume deles não seria um `or`ou `and`?

Comment: pois é, eu nao sei como fazer isso no doctrine, tentei por embaixo do where um ->AND, ou do lado do primeiro where () AND, mas tambem nao rolou

Answer (score 1):

Vou supor que você está passando a data atual por meio do parâmetro `$date`, que é um `\DateTime`. Sua *query* ficaria assim:

```
$this->noticia = Doctrine::getTable('Noticias')->createQuery('s')
    ->select('s.*')
    ->where("situacao = 'ativo'")
    ->where('data_validade < :data')
    ->orderBy('data_cadastro desc')
    ->setParameter('data', $data->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
    ->execute();
```

Comment: '$data = date("Y-m-d") 

$this->noticia = Doctrine::getTable('Noticias')->createQuery('s')
       ->select('s.*')
                        ->where("situacao = ?", 'ativo')
                        ->where("data_validade < :data") 
       ->orderBy('data_cadastro desc')
       ->limit(5) // temp
       ->execute();'

Comment: mas não foi aqui

Comment: Faltou colocar o `setParameter` a fim de colocar a data no parâmetro `data`.

Comment: hum, testei aqui de novo, mas nao foi, esse meu 'data_validade' no banco ele é um dado do tipo Date, troquei o setParameter ali para ->format('Y-m-d') mas tambem nao foi :/

Comment: Tente passar diretamente o objeto `\DateTime`, sem chamar  método `format`.

Comment: Uma dica: fique de olho no log de queries do Doctrine para ver a consulta que ele está fazendo no seu banco.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22339/discussion-between-estacio-di-fabio-and-rodrigo-rigotti).